# When editing a rc file, then opening it in VC Dialog Wizard, I get error RC2104 because of TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, mfc, slider

I have a VC++/MFC dialog-based project.
In those dialogs, I'm using some sliders with "Notify Before Move" at true.
Sometimes, instead of using VS dialog wizard to edit them, I prefer to edit the related .rc file manually in a text editor.

The issue is, after editing the .rc file, when I'm trying to open a dialog in VS wizard again, I get this error:
"error RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE"
I can still compile the project successfully, but I cannot open the project resources with VS wizard anymore.
The workaround is to remove manually the keyword, then I can re-open resources with the wizard, but I have to set every slider "Notify Before Move" setting at true again...

I don't understand why I get this error despite the project still compiling fine. If possible, I want to avoid the error and having to go through this workaround each time. Does anybody know how to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of the value for the _WIN32_WINNT macro you selected.  The TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE style flag is only available in later versions of Windows.  You must select at least 0x501.  Or in other words, your program won't be able to run on Windows 2000 (version 0x500) or earlier.  That's not much of a problem these days so bump up the value.

Comment: When I define _WIN32_WINNT to 0x501, all the APIs for Vista+ cannot be used anymore. But when I put it to 0x600, I get other compilation errors, as if some WinXP APIs has been disabled...
Yes, I have a project that needs to work on WinXP+

Comment: I cannot see your screen from here, no idea what "other compilation errors" could mean.

Comment: I tried to define it to 0x601, as it seems I'm using some Win7+ only API as well. It works but then I just come back to the same situation as before...Still need to use the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I add

```
#include <windows.h>
```

in the Resource.h, and solved it!