# MSVS 2017: Resoure Editor RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE

Tags: winapi, visual-studio-2017, resource-editor

Had a project that worked fine, edited the resources all the time.   This time I went in via right click, edit file, removed the IDR_MAINFRAME_256 toolbar references since going to just use one toolbar.  However, after saving the file and going back in, now it won't open giving the subject message  `RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: TBS_NOTIFYBEFOREMOVE`

I did a comparison of changes (including everything in the project), there are no include or other changes, just the two items I took out that referenced IDR_MAINFRAME_256.  I can compile it fine, just can't open resource editor.   What the heck happened and how do I clear it?

TIA!!

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/374632/tbs-notifyremove-confuses-resource-editor.html

Comment: Reads like the same issue as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10349841/1889329).

Comment: yes, it's the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the ultimate answer, but one thing that works is adding `#include <windows.h>` to the `resource.h` file.